# Can I improve threejs to make a huge group of boxes render faster without lug?

Tags: javascript

I'm here because I have a trouble with threejs. I tried to generate a infinite flat terrain with this code, posted in http://cubecraft.surge.sh/:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.js"></script>
<script>
setTimeout(()=>{
  k=[]
  xa=0
  ya=0
  onkeydown=onkeyup=(e)=>{k[e.keyCode]=e.type=="keydown"}
  document.body.requestPointerLock=document.body.requestPointerLock||document.body.mozRequestPointerLock
  document.title="Islandcraft."
  document.body.style.margin=0
  scene=new THREE.Scene()
  camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,innerWidth/innerHeight,0.1,10000)
  renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
  g=(x,y,z)=>{
    cube=new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1),new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:"rgb(100,50,0)"}))
    scene.add(cube)
    cube.position.set(x,y,z)
  }
  size=prompt("Enter the extension.")
  height=prompt("Enter the height.")
  for(x=-size;x<size;x++){
    for(y=-height;y<height;y++){
      for(z=-size;z<size;z++){
        if(Math.random()<1/2){
          g(x,y,z)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  scene.background=new THREE.Color("rgb(200,200,200)")
  scene.fog=new THREE.Fog("rgb(200,200,200)",0.01,10)
  light=new THREE.PointLight("rgb(255,255,255)",1,10)
  scene.add(light)
  onmousedown=()=>{
    if(document.pointerLockElement===document.body||
    document.mozPointerLockElement===document.body){
    }else{
      document.body.requestPointerLock()
    }
  }
  onmousemove=(event)=>{
    if(document.pointerLockElement===document.body||
    document.mozPointerLockElement===document.body){
      xa-=0.01*event.movementX
      if(-1.5<ya&&0<event.movementY){
        ya-=0.01*event.movementY
      }
      if(ya<1.5&&event.movementY<0){
        ya-=0.01*event.movementY
      }
    }
  }
  render=()=>{
    renderer.setSize(innerWidth,innerHeight)
    camera.aspect=innerWidth/innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    requestAnimationFrame(render)
    renderer.render(scene,camera)
  }
  render()
  setInterval(()=>{
    light.position.x=camera.position.x
    light.position.y=camera.position.y
    light.position.z=camera.position.z
    camera.lookAt(
      camera.position.x+Math.sin(xa)*Math.cos(ya),
      camera.position.y+Math.sin(ya),
      camera.position.z+Math.cos(xa)*Math.cos(ya)
    )
    if(k[65]){
      camera.position.x+=0.01*Math.cos(xa)
      camera.position.z-=0.01*Math.sin(xa)
    }
    if(k[87]){
      camera.position.x+=0.01*Math.sin(xa)
      camera.position.z+=0.01*Math.cos(xa)
    }
    if(k[68]){
      camera.position.x-=0.01*Math.cos(xa)
      camera.position.z+=0.01*Math.sin(xa)
    }
    if(k[83]){
      camera.position.x-=0.01*Math.sin(xa)
      camera.position.z-=0.01*Math.cos(xa)
    }
    if(k[32]){
      camera.position.y+=0.01
    }
    if(k[88]){
      camera.position.y-=0.01
    }
  },1)
},1)
</script>
```

The code really generates a flat random cracked terrain with optional extension and optional height of the terrain. The worst trouble is that the code is very laggy and slow when the extension or the optional height is more high than 8. How could I solve it?